# How to carry out uploading multiple files in Django with CreateView?

Tags: python, django

Please help me. I am new to Django, cannot undertsand the following thing - I have subclass of CreateView for creating a comment. I want to create a project where people can leave their comments and attach files (images) to this comment. One should have possibility to attach as many images as he wants to ONE form with text comment. I have found in Internet a decision that I need to use 2 models - 1 model for text comment + 1 separate model for images. Is it so?

Comment (text) form is created and handled in my views.py by sublass of CreateView. How to connect new separate model for images with my CreateView ?

```
models.py

class Descriptions(models.Model):
…
city = models.ForeignKey(Cities, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
description = models.TextField()
date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
…
class Description_Photos(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
    description = models.ForeignKey(Descriptions, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='photos')

forms.py

class DescriptionsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Descriptions
        exclude = []
        widgets = {'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols':90})}

class Photos_form(forms.Form):
    photos = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))

views.py

class DescriptionCreate(CreateView):
    model = Descriptions
    form_class = DescriptionsForm
    template_name = 'countries/new_description.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('countries:descr', args=[self.kwargs['country_id'], self.kwargs['city_id']])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        self.city = get_object_or_404(Cities, id=self.kwargs['city_id'])
        kwargs['city'] = self.city
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.city = get_object_or_404(Cities, id=self.kwargs['city_id'])
        form.instance.owner = self.request.user
        messages.success(self.request, 'Your post has been added, thank you')
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

So my question is what should I write in views.py for `class Photos_form(forms.Form):` ? How to connect this class and my `class DescriptionCreate(CreateView)` ?

Comment: Well, if you need django forms for photo fields, you just pass the form in your context data and get your data in `form_valid`. Actually you don't need to have `photos_form`. Easiest way is sending form data in html (make your file input in html) and save inside `form_valid`

Comment: In Django official documentation it is requred to have form for separate model which handles files:     
    class FileFieldForm(forms.Form):
        file_field = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))'

Comment: I don't understand what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use for same situations FormSets https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/

Declare FormSet for images models

```
…

# forms.py

class DescriptionsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Descriptions
        exclude = []
        widgets = {'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols':90})}

class Photos_form(forms.Form):
    photos = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))


##### Declare FORMSET !!! ###
class BasePhotosFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):

    """By default, when you create a formset from a model, the formset
    will use a queryset that includes all objects in the model"""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'city' in kwargs.keys():
            city = kwargs.pop('city')
        else:
            city = None
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if city and isinstance(instance, Cities):
            self.queryset = Description_Photos.objects.filter(city=city)
        else:
            self.queryset = Description_Photos.objects.none()

# I usually declare formset for create operations and formset for update operations separately          
PhotosCreateFormSet = forms.modelformset_factory(Description_Photos, Photos_form,
                                                    fields=Photos_form.Meta.fields, extra=0,
                                                    formset=BasePhotosFormSet)


PhotosUpdateFormSet = forms.modelformset_factory(Description_Photos, Photos_form, can_delete=True,
                                              fields=PropertyImageForm.Meta.fields, extra=0,
                                              formset=BasePhotosFormSet)


#############

# views.py

class DescriptionCreate(CreateView):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            images_formset = PhotosCreateFormSet(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES, city=self.object)
        else:
            images_formset = PhotosCreateFormSet(instance=self.object)
        context['formset'] = images_formset
        context['city'] = self.object
        return context
```

**Templates**

```html
    <div id="img-form-template" style="display: none">
       <!- Declare EMPTY FORM for dynamically rebuild user interface by jQuery, for example->
      {{ formset.empty_form }}
    </div>
    ...
    <div id="my-images">
        ...
        {{ formset.management_form }}
        {% for image_form in formset %}
            {{ image_form }}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    ...
    <script>
      ...
      <!- Any javascript code to dynamically create empty form based on template "#img-form-template" ->
      ...
    </script>
```

I've tried to rewrite my custom code to your variant. 
I suppose it is a bad idea to declare `self.city` in your example as creation model instance: Django automatically create `self.object`

Comment: But this is not decision. I want people to load as many images as they want to 1 post (1 form). One wants attach 5 photos to 1 post, another may want to attach 7 photos to 1 post. Every time different qty. Formset enables to attach limited (set by parameter 'extra') qty of images. Is not it so??

Comment: No, extra param set count of visible empty forms, I usually set extra to 0 cause I favour to manipulate forms dynamically by Javascript. I can public code of my last project with adding photos of flats for rent site

Comment: Pavel, yes, please public Django-code for this problem. I completely don't understand how to combine CreateView and multiple forms.

Comment: Thank you very much! Will try to puzzle out.

Comment: You can set extra >0 to debug/experiment view template

Comment: @Александр Грайс
did you achieve your goal?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have found your answer, I have done something, but may not be the cleaned or recommended one;

I have a page for multiple images upload and another page to view the images, add additional information and complete the process. Between the pages, I have used session to pass a parent table ID through which I group multiple images being uploaded.

Below is my class for image upload:

```
class UploadImages(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
```

In get_context_data, I do the below (summarized):

```
if "album_id" not in self.request.session:
        print("Creating a temporary album!")
        album = Album(
            owner = self.request.user,
            category_id = 6,#others
            privacy_id=3,#restricted
            status_id=8,#temporary file
            title="Temporary Album for " + self.request.user.get_full_name(),
            is_temp=True
        )

        album.save()

        self.request.session['album_id'] = album.id

context.update({
        'taid':album_id,
    })

    return context
```

When I re-direct to this view from the menu, all session IDs with album_id are clearer, this way it will get called for the first time. Each time a single file uploads, this method will be called inside form_valid and hence, it is good to validate and then create for the firs time. In the HTML template, I have this javascript variable to hold the redirect url after successful file upload, in ajax call:

```
<script>
  var redirect_url = "{% url 'images:complete-upload' %}"
</script>
```

Then in form_valid:

```
if self.request.is_ajax():
        album_id = self.request.session['album_id']
```

Now I have access to the album_id and I can use this to save multiple images, grouped into one album:

```
lnk_album = AlbumPhotos(
            album_id = album_id,
            photo = self.object
        )

        lnk_album.save()
```

Once this is done for each single message, my ajax call returns success, in the javascript file, I do this:

```
$("#fileupload").fileupload({
  dataType: 'json',
  sequentialUploads: true,  /* 1. SEND THE FILES ONE BY ONE */
  start: function (e) {  /* 2. WHEN THE UPLOADING PROCESS STARTS, SHOW THE MODAL */
    $("#modal-progress").modal("show");
  },
  stop: function (e) {  /* 3. WHEN THE UPLOADING PROCESS FINALIZE, HIDE THE MODAL */
    $("#modal-progress").modal("hide");

    //write code to re-direct
    window.location.replace(redirect_url);
  },
  progressall: function (e, data) {  /* 4. UPDATE THE PROGRESS BAR */
    var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
    var strProgress = progress + "%";
    $(".progress-bar").css({"width": strProgress});
    $(".progress-bar").text(strProgress);
  },
  done: function (e, data) {
      console.log("completed file upload!")
    if (data.result.is_valid) {
        console.log("success!!")
    }
    else{
        console.log(e)
    }
  }

});
```

This gets job done for me so far. I haven't figured out whether this is a best practice. Once I do a penetration testing, maybe in a month or so, after completing this app, I will know (or someone else points out the vulnerabilities in this code).

On the receiving page, I pick up the album_id from the session (get_context_data) and then delete it to ensure the session is clean.

I hope this helps.