# How to create a class-based view for multiple file uploads

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am uploading multiple files and I would like to use classes in the `models.py`, `forms.py`, and also `views.py` so that I the code is easily changeable in one place and reused.

The issue I am having is not understanding how to implement a class-based view for file uploads that allows me to create instances for reuse.

I have tried to implement a class-based view as as shown below but I believe I need to insert an **init** method and insert `self.` on the attributes but I am confused being that there are functions such as `reverse_lazy` in the attributes.

My views.py

```
class FileUploadView(View):
    form_class = DocumentForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home') # want different url for every instance
    template_name = 'file_upload.html' # same for template_name

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(self.success_url)
        else:
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

EDIT: As Gasanov suggested, you can insert the `success_url` and `template_name` as parameters in the `url_patterns` as such:

```
urlpatterns = [    
path('stylist/', payroll_views.FileUploadView.as_view(
        success_url=reverse_lazy('landing.html'), template_name='stylist.html'), name='stylist'),
]
```

This allows for reuse of the class-based view in a clean and pragmatic way.

Comment: You need to create attributes in the init method if you want to use them in your methods. reverse_lazy maybe available because it is not part of the FileUploadView class namespace.

Comment: please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51510373/how-to-carry-out-uploading-multiple-files-in-django-with-createview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where you want to declare different `success_url` or `template_name`, but you can do it in `urls.py` like this:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('a/', FileUploadView.as_view(success_url=reverse_lazy('home'), template_name='index1.html')),
    path('b/', FileUploadView.as_view(success_url=reverse_lazy('nothome'), template_name='index2.html'))
]
```

Comment: I had not realized I could do this. I will edit my post again to show how you solved the issue. Thank you very much!! This is definitely the cleanest and most pragmatic way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could benefit from using `FormView` instead of `View`, because you are basically reimplementing `post` from there.

In order to "overwrite" `success_url` and `template_name`, there are already methods that do just that:

```py
class FileUploadView(FormView):
    ...
    def get_success_url(self):
        if blahblah:
            return something
        else:
            return something_else

    def get_template_names(self):
        if blahblah:
            return ['some/template.html']
        else:
            return ['another/template.html']
```